# Can you validate the two factor code by the api in fusionauth

Tags: fusionauth

I have a question about fusionauth and its 2FA API. 
we want to use 2fa in our app but only under some circumstances and not on every login. 
I found that there is API to send a code via SMS but I can't seem to find an API to verify it. 
can anyone help me?

I looked at the [docs](https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/apis/two-factor#send-a-two-factor-code) and there is only send and enable/disable no verify, can it be somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

The API does support a trust mode, but there is not currently a separate API for selective 2FA.

There is not an API to validate the code, instead you utilize the Two Factor Login API to complete the login process. This implicitly validates the code.

https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/apis/login#complete-two-factor-authentication